# Recording Issue in JMeter - SSO (desktop application)

Tags: jmeter, single-sign-on, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, banking

I am trying to record a desktop application(banking application) in JMeter .Application uses SSO for sign in .While recording application in JMeter I am facing below error.

I have already tried adding authorization manager as well as changed implementation to Java , but in vain.

**Error in JMeter** :-

ERROR o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPJavaImpl: readResponse: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://
2020-07-29 12:08:38,024 ERROR o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPJavaImpl: Cause: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://

**Error at client side**
The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate' . the Authentication header received from server was 'Negotiate ,NTLM'

Please Note :- won't be able to use blazemeter tool or any other internet requiring tool for recording or for conversion of HAR files

Any help will be highly appreciated

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 0):

In addition to adding the [HTTP Authorization Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) you need to properly configure it and specify your username, password, domain and `BASIC_DIGEST` as the "Mechanism"

[image]

More information:

- [NT LAN Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NT_LAN_Manager)
- [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter)

Also be aware that you can always split your recording session and record separately:

1. Login procedure
2. The actions after the login

Comment: Hi Dmitri .Basic_digest is not working . Also recording session and record separately . how can this be achieved ?